# Confusion in Struts 2 MVC architecture

Tags: java, model-view-controller, architecture, struts2, struts

I am studying the [Struts2 in Action](http://www.amazon.in/Struts-2-Action-Don-Brown/dp/193398807X) and come to know that Controller in Struts 2 is `FilterDispatcher` and `Model` is `Action`.

But previously I knew that `Action` and `FilterDispatcher` both are Controllers and Struts does not provide support to Model layer. Which one of the above is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that FilterDispatcher is a [FrontController](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html) and Action is both Model and Controller in one class.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Struts2 `Action`s are *controller delegates*. And Struts2 provides a `valueStack` on the View layer which has an `Action` on top of it, and if you want to use a *pseudo-model* then action should implement `ModelDriven` interface.

You should also **note** that Struts2 actions are simple POJOs managed by Struts2 container. This is a bit different in the MVC point of view, also known as MVC Model2. For example, the description of the *model* given by [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

> The central component of MVC, the *model*, captures the behavior of the application in terms of its [problem domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_domain), independent of the user interface.<sup>[[5]](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface)</sup> The model directly manages the data, logic and rules of the application.

From this point of view a Business Model is defined separately from the View Model and often being managed by Persistence layer. Struts2 controller works with the View Model via its delegates.

> The View can be any output representation of information, such as a chart or a diagram; multiple views of the same information are possible, such as a bar chart for management and a tabular view for accountants.

In Struts2 the View is a `Result` returned by the controller in `response` object. Struts2 can use different result types and templates to produce a response.

> The Controller, accepts input and converts it to commands for the model or view<sup>[[6]](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25057/Simple-Example-of-MVC-Model-View-Controller-Design)</sup>.

Struts2 uses a `request` for the input, which is handled by the `Action` to find appropriate delegate, which can work with the View Model directly or use a Service layer.

In Struts2 an `Action` is a Controller, it's a simple POJO which is also a Model.

Struts2 can help you with the Controller via `ActionSupport` and presenting a View, it's also pushes `Action` to the `valueStack` to have access from the View. You can design a Model via associating your Business Model with the View Model.