# Which files are responsible specifically for Model, View and Controller in struts2 MVC framework?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, struts2, architectural-patterns

My MVC concept is not clear.

It seems me that  `.xml` files are for *Modeling*; `.jsp` files are for *Viewing*; `.java` files are for *Controlling*. This is actually represents MVC system.

I have the working basic concepts on MVC formula but I am not clear on which files are responsible specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, dive into [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Your conception of MVC is wrong, and so is dividing *concepts* using technologies (.xml, .jsp, .java...);

[image]

- The **Model** *contains* the data (WHAT is displayed);
- The **View** *renders* the data to the user (HOW it is displayed);
- The **Controller** *manipulates* the data, both automatically or based on user's interaction (WHY it is displayed).

Then, when you've clear what MVC is, try to understand how Struts2 implements MVC:

- the **JSP** file is the **View**;
- the **Action** is the **Controller** ([and part of the Model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36579657/1654265));
- the **Model** is whatever you use to carry the data (Bean, POJO, Map, String, etc...), unless you explicitly define a model object through ModelDriven (but don't), in which case that object is the Model.

---

**EDIT**: as suggested by Dave, it is worth mentioning that, when talking of Actions, we're also implying the StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter (responsible of which Action to call) and the Interceptor Stack (through which every Action must pass before - and after - a result execution).

Comment: (I'd argue the controller is the filter and the interceptors. Controllers decide what should handle requests.)

Comment: @Dave yes, there're many interpretations where the Filter is presented as Controller and the Action as Model. Others says that the Filter (along with the interceptors) is a front-controller, and the action is the MVC controller in the strict sense... there's a lot of contamination between terms and concepts and a neat distinction is not always possible; I refuse the idea of [representing the Action as simply "the Model"](https://www.dunebook.com/5-best-java-framework-to-learn-in-2017/) though, and the term "Action" IMHO implies Filter and Stack too: an action cant' work without them